# MySQL Query for AND condition

Tags: mysql

I am having a table with structure and data as below:

1. categories: has_many sub_categories

> ```
> +----+---------------+  
> | id | category_name |  
> +----+---------------+  
> |  1 | Confectionery |  
> |  2 | Drinks        |    
> +----+---------------+
> ```

2. sub categories: belongs_to :categories

> ```
> +----+-------------+-------------------+  
> | id | category_id | sub_categpry_name |  
> +----+-------------+-------------------+  
> |  1 |           1 | chocolate cookies |  
> |  2 |           2 | chocolate shake   |  
> |  3 |           2 | cookie shake      |    
> +----+-------------+-------------------+
> ```

I am doing a search in this two tables. My search keyword is "**Chocolate AND Cookies**". This should search in the sub categories table and should return the category of the sub category. The word "Chocolate" is available in row 2 and cookie is available in row 3 but both the sub categories belong to the same category and Hence it should return the 2nd category. But my below query returns only my 1st category.

```
SELECT cat.id,cat.category_name,sub.sub_category_name 
FROM categories cat JOIN sub_categories sub 
WHERE cat.id = sub.category_id and sub.sub_category_name REGEXP '[[:<:]]Chocolate[[:>:]]' AND sub.sub_category_name REGEXP '[[:<:]]Cookies[[:>:]]'
```

Anyone, please suggest how to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your want to take the category name of all matched sub categories?

Comment: Yes I want to take the category

Comment: So how about fiddle link i have attached with my answer. Is it ok or not?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that only the 1st subcategory has both `chocolate` and `cookies` in it, the 2nd has only `chocolate`. Because of the `and`, both keywords have to be present in the **same** `sub_categpry_name` field. Just a reminder: the 3rd record will not match any searches because it has the word `cookie`, but you are searching for `cookies`.

The simplest solution is to use `or` instead of `and`:

```
SELECT cat.id,cat.category_name,sub.sub_category_name 
FROM categories cat INNER JOIN sub_categories sub 
on cat.id = sub.category_id 
where sub.sub_category_name REGEXP '[[:<:]]Chocolate[[:>:]]' OR sub.sub_category_name REGEXP '[[:<:]]Cookies[[:>:]]'
```

A better solution would be to move to [fulltext indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html) and [fulltext search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html).

Adding a fulltext index:

```
alter table sub_categories add index subcat_name_ft (sub_category_name)
```

Fulltext search:

```
SELECT cat.id,cat.category_name,sub.sub_category_name 
FROM categories cat INNER JOIN sub_categories sub 
on cat.id = sub.category_id 
where match(sub.sub_category_name) against ('chocolate cookies' in Boolean mode)
```

Just make sure you familiarise yourself with fulltext search restrictions (min word length, stopwords, nose, etc) and features.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your requirement could be interpreted to finding the category which has sub categories matched both *Chocolate* AND *Cookies* keywords.
You could try.

```
SELECT cat.id, 
       cat.category_name 
FROM   categories cat 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   sub_categories sub1 
               WHERE  cat.id = sub1.category_id 
                      AND sub1.sub_category_name LIKE '%Chocolate%') 
       AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM   sub_categories sub2 
                   WHERE  cat.id = sub2.category_id 
                          AND sub2.sub_category_name LIKE '%Cookies%')
```

If you want to get information of sub categories, you could update the query to join with table sub categories.

Comment: Different interpretation of the requirements, but may be equally right. If you added some explanation as to what your query does, then this would get my vote.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
SELECT cat.id, cat.category_name, GROUP_CONCAT(scat.sub_category_name ORDER By 
  scat.sub_category_name) AS sub_category
FROM categories AS cat
LEFT JOIN sub_categories AS scat ON scat.category_id = cat.id
WHERE scat.sub_category_name LIKE '%Chocolate%' OR scat.sub_category_name LIKE '%Cookie%'
GROUP BY cat.id
```

and fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b2cacc/6)

Comment: I cannot use OR condition in this scenario. If my search keyword is "Chocolate OR Cookies" then i can use OR condition in it. But my AND condition is totally different. It should work as Boolean operator search

Comment: @SuriyaPrabha your desired out put should contain only category 2 or both of them according to your data sample.

Comment: I need both of them